# electron-builder shows missing dependices after compile

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I trying to build an Electron app. For that I'm using the following respos:
https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start
https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder

In development mode (electron .) everything works fine. But when I build the app and starting it, it just loads pretty much the page, but it's datepicker from the node modules is missing, a without any errors in the dev console or build log.

Why doesn't it work in production? All my files are in one direction:

- index.html
- main.js
- renderer.js
- package.json

I didn't changed much in the base package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "twitter-dm-scheduler",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "TBD",
  "main": "main.js",
  "buildDependenciesFromSource": "true",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "dist": "electron-builder",
    "pack": "electron-builder --dir",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps"
  },
  "author": "TBD",
  "license": "CC0-1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^10.1.3",
    "electron-builder": "^22.8.1",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.31",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "zebra_datepicker": "^1.9.15"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "bulma-calendar": "^6.0.9",
    "electron-context-menu": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.electron.twitterdmscheduler",
    "productName": "Twitter DM Scheduler",
    "directories": {
      "output": "build"
    },
    "nsis": {
      "oneClick": true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^10.1.3",
    "electron-builder": "^22.8.1",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.31",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "zebra_datepicker": "^1.9.15"
  },
```

While packaging, the electron-builder won't pack the `devDeps` so you can't use this `jquery`, `moment` after packaging.

Move these deps to your `dependencies`

Comment: I tried that, and unfortunately yet the dependencies STILL doesen't show up, Bootstrap loads, but not jquery, datepicker, or any node modules installed. It worked on the original electron build **before** using the builder. now, some of which is missing. Is there something in the [electron-builder guide](https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration) that i"m missing? I'm trying to get the dependences to fit into the builder.